# How to, programmatically, change the SSL/TLS support using WinInet?

Tags: windows, delphi, ssl, tls1.2, wininet

Sometimes I need to deal with the "Advanced Tab" of Internet Options to enable/disable some SSL/TLS protocols to satisfy some applications. Now I want to know if it is possible do this enable/disable programmaticaly, per application connection, these protocols. Is this possible? If yes, how?